# Would it be possible to add some code to this topic model script to enable non r trained colleagues to use it easily?

Tags: r, shiny, topic-modeling

I have a topic model script which I would like to make available as a shiny app

I have not got any experience using shiny and this will be my first effort. The input will always be an excel sheet with the same format, and I want the output to be an excel sheet with the topic model topics and sub topics. The script currently works fine but I want it to be available when I move onto a different team.

```
F<-read.csv("SourceandText2.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

F$charsinfeedback<-sapply(F$Text, function(x) nchar(x))
F$wordsinfeedback<-sapply(strsplit(F$Text, "\\s+"), length)
head(F$charsinfeedback)
F_stem<-str_replace_all(F$Text,"@","")  
F_stem<-stemDocument(F_stem)
F_stem<-removePunctuation(F_stem)
F_stem<-tolower(F_stem)
F_stem<-stripWhitespace(F_stem)
F<-cbind(F,F_stem)

extendedstopwords<-c("a","amp","hark","day","via","harkiv","music","â€", "â€“", "â€“
", "itâ€™s","â·â", "donâ€™t" )
extendedstopwords<-c(extendedstopwords,
                     gsub("'","",grep("'",extendedstopwords,value = T)))

dtm.control<-list(
  tolower=T,
  removePunctuation=T,
  removeNumbers=T,
  stopwords=c(stopwords("english")),
  stemming=F,
  wordLengths=c(3,Inf),
  weighting=weightTf
)

dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(F_stem)),
                        control = dtm.control)

dim(dtm)
dtm<-removeSparseTerms(dtm,0.999)
dim(dtm)

matrix<-as.matrix(dtm)

freq<-colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
length(freq)
ord<-order(freq,decreasing = T)
freq[head(ord)]
freq[tail(ord)]

findFreqTerms(dtm,lowfreq = 50)

set.seed(42)
wordcloud(names(freq),freq,min.freq = 10,colors = brewer.pal(6,"Dark2"))

burnin<-4000
iter<-2000
thin<-500
seed<-list(2003,5,63,10001,765)
nstart<-5
best<-TRUE

K<-10

rowTotals<-apply(dtm,1,sum)
empty.rows<-dtm[rowTotals==0,]$dimnames[1][[1]]
corpus3<-F_stem[as.numeric(empty.rows)]

dtm<-dtm[rowTotals>0,]
dim(dtm)
ldaOut3<-LDA(dtm,K,method="Gibbs", control=list(nstart=nstart, seed=seed, best=best, burnin=burnin, iter=iter, thin=thin))

ldaOut3.topics<-as.matrix(terms(ldaOut3))
write.csv(ldaOut3.topics, file = paste("LDAGibbs",K,"K3DocsToTopics.csv"))

ldaOut3.terms<-as.matrix(terms(ldaOut3,10))
write.csv(ldaOut3.terms,file = paste("LDAGibbs",K,"TopicsToTerms.csv"))

topicProbabilities3<-as.data.frame(ldaOut3@gamma)
write.csv(topicProbabilities3,file = paste("LDAGibbs",K,"TopicProbabilities.csv"))
```

Comment: I'm quite certain the answer to your question is "yes". You might want to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could write this as a shiny app. Use the `fileInput()` function to allow the user to input an excel file and the `downloadButton()` to allow the user to download an output file at the end. You should try to convert your code to shiny and ask a specific question if you run into problems.